# Angular: Module was created but never loaded

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-module

I am have trying to fix this but not able to find a solution since a long time. I an angular newbie and trying to make my website home an angular app. The angular app has a controller and 2-3 directives. In the head section of the page I have:
Home.cshtml:

```
<head>
    //Some other stuff....
    <script src="/Scripts/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/myapp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="HomeController">
       <page-tile-grid></page-tile-grid>
    </div>
</body>
```

And myapp.js has

```
var myapp= angular.module('myapp', [])
                  .controller("HomeController", function($scope){......})
                  .directive('page-tile-grid', function () {....})
                  .directive('page-tiles', function () {....})
                  .directive('page-tile-info', function () {....})
```

I see no error on the console. But template in the directive does not load. And see this warning on the Batarang Angular console:

```
Module "myapp" was created but never loaded.
```

Comment: Is there any other script you are trying to load before angular.js? And if so, is it some angular dependency?

Comment: Are you using angular-hints ??

Comment: Yes I am including script for bootstrap before angular. I am not sure if I need to include any other dependency since I am not doing any fancy in these controllers. Any way I can find out if I am missing out some dependency? angular-hints is giving me that message I mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0):

What if you try something like:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.title = "Homepage";
    ...
});

app.controller('AboutCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.title = "About";
    ...
});
```

Comment: Any particular reason for down-voting?